# How to completely control Laravel Excel customValidationMessages output messages?

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I am currently using Laravel Excel to import data from an excel file into database. When there are some errors occur, I'd like it to report in a foreign language rather than in English which I know I have to use customValidationMessages() function to define the output messages.

This is an example of regular messages:

> There was an error on row 2. The somefield has already been taken.
> There was an error on row 3. The somefield has already been taken.

Which consists of 2 parts

> There was an error on row {some_row}. is the first part.
> and 
> The somefield has already been taken. is the last part

and when I follow the document provided here https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html#custom-validation-messages all I can output in the foreign language is just the last part but the first part remains in English like this.

> There was an error on row 2. ข้อความในภาษาต่างประเทศ
> There was an error on row 3. ข้อความในภาษาต่างประเทศ

But I want it to be like this

> ข้อความภาษาต่างประเทศแถวที่ 2. ข้อความในภาษาต่างประเทศ
> ข้อความภาษาต่างประเทศแถวที่ 3. ข้อความในภาษาต่างประเทศ

How can I do it???

Thank you all in advance

Answer (score 1):

after inspect the library source, it looks like they use the laravel's localization for that part too: `__('There was an error on row :row. :message', ['row' => $this->row, 'message' => $message]);`

https://github.com/SpartnerNL/Laravel-Excel/blob/44e165b73eaf182a2f699d905a20684889675b1c/src/Validators/Failure.php#L82

so you can define your own localization message like: `"There was an error on row :row. :message" => "ข้อความภาษาต่างประเทศแถวที่ 2 (change to your own message because I don't really know your language)",`